# Adjusting position of individual graduated symbols in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, mapping

[image]

The house symbols in the map are overlapping each other.

Is there any tool in ArcMap that I can manually move symbols individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the houses feature to graphic that can let you move them manually. Just right-click the houses layer in the table of content and choose [Convert Features to Graphics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/converting-between-graphics-and-features-convertin.htm).

[image]

It is better to check [Understanding converting between graphics and features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/converting-between-graphics-and-features-about-con.htm) for more information.